# c# Sockets sending Length of the Data

Tags: c#, sockets

I m using Tcp Protocol on my server/client Application , since its stream oriented protocol i need to keep receiving till i hit the size of the data sent .
if i send The Length of data First

```
 byte[] Data; //this is the data
 byte[] DataLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(Data.Length); // Length of the data
```

while The Size of DataLength can't exceed 4 bytes

```
Socket.Receive(BufferLength,0,4,0); // receiving lenth
```

does it still  not confirmed to receive the bytes that holds the full length of the data that will be sent in one receive ? so that i can know how much i need to call the receive method for the nexts coming bytes ?

**edit** : i only want to know one receive call can't get the length of the data that will be sent ? can't surely get 4 bytes in one call ?

for Example My data Length is 1024 I took that length i encoded it to byte[] then i send it first does one call is able to get that length in one call ?

Comment: No, you can't know how much data you will receive in advance. Simply receive as much as you can and then determine what you actually got. This usually means you have to copy data to intermediate buffers, since (for example) you could get one complete item and then half of another.

Comment: Yes you can get 4 bytes in one call, but I would use an array of a well-known dimension. byte[4] instead of byte[]

Comment: @mcNets Its exactly what i wanted to know :) Thanks sir its an answer

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert its not about the actual data but the data Length while it can exceed the size of  4 bytes i sent those 4 bytes first the question is  can i receive that 4 bytes in one call

Comment: Note that calling `.Receive` with an array of length 4 will *not* guarantee you will get 4 bytes. It will guarantee you'll get *no more than 4 bytes*. This is the kind of code that will often work but can still fail (for example, if the other size turns off Nagle and sends individual bytes).

Comment: Maybe not for the first message. The first four bytes will _probably_ (but nobody guarantees this) end up in one `receive()` buffer. However, you should cater for the case where two messages are sent after another, so `[L1][P1][L2][P2]`, where the payload of the first, and the length of the second message are spread over various packets.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod very nice article, read the 12 points about buffer (scroll down)

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert yes so i basically needs to keep receiving First to get the size (4 bytes) then create  a bytes of the Size received and keep calling receive again for the data

Comment: @bakapanda: there are more efficient approaches, but yes, that will work. In fact, the linked question demonstrates exactly this technique.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert Thanks sir!  do you have any other approache ?

Comment: @bakapanda: Not one I could write up as an answer. The basic idea is to always read as much as possible, then inspect your buffer to see what you have, to minimize the number of `.Receive` calls and allocations. So loop first until you have at least 4 bytes, but do it on a large buffer so you have also already read some of the packet(s), not a buffer of only 4 bytes. But then you also have to buffer data and/or copy it around and/or interpret it... efficient TCP/IP code could be a book, and this comment's too small to contain it.